# angular material autocomplete enhancement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i follow this guide to my project 
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete and 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material/angular_material_autocomplete.htm

in the example they load the state first to search a state. and then you can search the state this was a good example.

in my case how about when you search a name and there were 6k names or more that was a big problem to load and make my web more slower

so i give it a try to create my own. getting a resource while searching and this is what i come out.

here's my view (slim format)

```
div layout="row"
  md-autocomplete md-item-text="item.name" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in ctrl.getMatches(searchText)" md-no-cache="true" md-search-text="searchText" md-selected-item="item" md-floating-label="Client Name" flex=""
    md-item-template
      span md-highlight-flags="^i" md-highlight-text="searchText" 
        | {{item.name}}
```

my controller(coffee format)

```
 @getMatches = (searchText) =>
  deferred = $q.defer()
  if  searchText.length >= 2
    name = searchText
    test = Client::Search.query {name: name}, (data) =>
      states = data.clients
      if states.length == 0
        name = searchText + "*"
        test = Client::Search.query {name: name}, (data) =>
          states = data.clients
      $timeout (=>
        deferred.resolve states
        return
        ), 1000
    deferred.promise
  else
    test = []
```

when i get more than 2 letters in my search my resource will be trigger and will start searching. my problem if i search long word my web will be get slower.

additional:
 when i type every letter my server side will response example if i type uni(for university) the word uni will get to my server side and respond and so on and so on then when i complete the word "university" i have so many resource that cause me to slow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNIBc.png)

[image]

any idea how can inhance this and more faster???

Comment: Does this 6k names coming from server side ? ( a database?)

Comment: yes this is the process type>generate query if true>query to api and then  will get the id of the given name

Comment: then why don't you try search by using ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax call from server side, already answered here

[Angular Material autocomplete with $http call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854697/angular-material-autocomplete-with-http-call)

Comment: my code was perfectly working but i want to be more faster and i need enhancement

Comment: Yea i know that, If you want more faster don't keep large data in your client side, just search up from server side real time. That is why I suggested this method. When your client side holds large data, there is also possibility to load the website slowly.

Comment: ok the main problem this is when i type every letter my server side will response example if i type uni(for university) the word uni will get to my server side and respond and so on and so on then when i complete the word "university" i have so many resource that cause me to slow any idea???

Comment: assign that list to a static variable in server side and then search in that list while performing search. Then there will no heavy use of database. Fill the static variable from database at once whether it is null.

Answer (score 0):

this link helps me [How to write a debounce service in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320015/how-to-write-a-debounce-service-in-angularjs)
i use debounce to enhance my autocomplete hopes some help this thanks guys :) peace out